# how to use airflow macros with nodash to suffix to table name

Tags: macros, airflow, airflow-scheduler

i would like to suffix macros date with nodash to my final table . 
I am using the below macro

```
if sd = 2018-05-09 , {{macros.ds_add(ds, -4)}}
```

to get the current date - 4 date, getting out put like 2018-05-05. Expected output would be 20180505.

tried

```
{{{{macros.ds_add(ds, -4)}}_nodash}}
```

I'm getting the

> jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ':', got '}'

Assist me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `airflow.macros.ds_format` to format the dates as you want. For example:

```
airflow.macros.ds_format(airflow.macros.ds_add('2018-05-09',-4),'%Y-%m-%d','%Y%m%d')
```

More details: http://airflow.incubator.apache.org/code.html?highlight=macro#airflow.macros.ds_format